# Hibernate JPA select with parameter and multiple LIKE

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to make a little spring boot service that receives a parameter and then the query will apply a like to each word in the sentence. I want to know why this works:

```
    @GetMapping("/getAll")
//@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
private List<PersonaNegativa> getAll(){
    List<PersonaNegativa> listneg = new ArrayList<PersonaNegativa>();
    try {
        listneg = entityManager
                .createQuery("select p from PersonaNegativa p where p.NombreCompletoFonetico like '%ARKRP%' "
                        + "or p.NombreCompletoFonetico like '%ARLNS%'",
                        PersonaNegativa.class).getResultList();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
        return listneg;
    }
```

But this doesn't.

```
@GetMapping("/getNombre/{nom}")
private List<PersonaNegativa> getByNombre(@PathVariable String nom){
DoubleMetaphone dm = new DoubleMetaphone();
dm.setMaxCodeLen(5);
String[] nomarray = nom.split(" ");
String nomconvertido = "";
for(int i = 0; i<=nomarray.length-1; i++) {
    if(i< nomarray.length-1) {
    nomconvertido += "%" + dm.doubleMetaphone(nomarray[i])+ "% or p.NombreCompletoFonetico like ";
    }
    else {
    nomconvertido += "%" +dm.doubleMetaphone(nomarray[i]) + "%";
    }
}

System.out.println(nomconvertido);

List<PersonaNegativa> listneg = new ArrayList<PersonaNegativa>();
try {
    listneg = entityManager
            .createQuery("select p from PersonaNegativa p where p.NombreCompletoFonetico like :nom",
                    PersonaNegativa.class)
            .setParameter("nom", nomconvertido).getResultList();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
    return listneg;
}
```

}

when printing 'nomconvertido' I get this: "%ARKRP% or p.NombreCompletoFonetico like %ARLNS%"

which should give the same result as the test above, so i'm wondering why is it different.

Comment: So go and look at the SQL that was actually invoked (in the JPA providers log) and you understand better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you can't use the named parameter to add sql.  You're passing the whole set of like elements as a value, so you need to build up the JPQL the same way you do in the first instance.

I've added some sample code that I absolutely did not test to get you moving in the right direction.

```
@GetMapping("/getNombre/{nom}")
private List<PersonaNegativa> getByNombre(@PathVariable String nom) {
    DoubleMetaphone dm = new DoubleMetaphone();
    dm.setMaxCodeLen(5);

    int parameterCount = 0;
    StringBuilder clause = new StringBuilder();
    List<String> parameters = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String string : nom.split(" ")) {
        clause.append((clause.length() == 0) ? " p.NombreCompletoFonetico like ?" : " or p.NombreCompletoFonetico like ?");
        parameters.add("%" + dm.doubleMetaphone(string));

    }

    String jpaql = "select p from PersonaNegativa p where " + clause.toString();

    List<PersonaNegativa> listneg = new ArrayList<PersonaNegativa>();
    try {
        TypedQuery<PersonaNegativa> query = entityManager
                .createQuery(jpaql,
                        PersonaNegativa.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.size(); i++) {
            query.setParameter(i, parameters.get(i))
        }
        return query.getResultList();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining that to me, This was exactly what I needed to know, and i appreciate you took the time to improve my code.

Comment: :D Anytime, you're welcome.